# What are Starkiller Base's capabilities?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Are there any technical specifications or the equivalent mentioned anywhere for the following?

With a single shot, how many "bolts" can it split up into? Does the number of bolts decrease individual power? Enough to reduce likelihood of successful planetary destruction?

How do the bolts travel to its target, does it go through hyperspace, how fast are the bolts and why are they visible in the sky?

Comment: partial dupe  of [How did characters see this event happen in The Force Awakens?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111089/5184).

Comment: @phantom42 Yup, that question's answer explains that people can see the "bolts" and exploding planets 1/4 galaxy a way in real time, in no way that makes any sense at all, and that seems to have no "why".

Comment: @phantom42 - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112049/how-do-you-aim-the-starkiller-weapon/112086#112086, rather

Comment: Re: "why are they visible in the sky": Because they are made of Handwavium. it's a brand new just-discovered physics thing called in-universe "sub-hyperspace" and we don't have a first clue what it can or should look like, so they chose the most visually striking one. Also, you can see turbolaser bolts in vacuum in star wars, so you really can't expect JJAbrams to raise the game too much even if he wasn't JJAbrams

Comment: @thegreatJedi. - I'm closing this as a dupe, sorry. Since my VTC is binding (no need for 5 ppl), I'm very open to hearing a reason why the linked Q&A don't constitute a duplicate, and wouldn't take much to convince me to VTRO.